# Simple Twitter XML Feed Only Working 20% of the Time

Tags: php, xml, twitter

Worked with XML feeds before, but this one seems to be causing an error.

I am not experienced so please be gentle.

The following code should load in a Twitter feed using its XML address. And it does 20% of the time. The other times it returns in error. I have no idea why.

```
<?php 
   if(simplexml_load_file('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/quitecheesedoff.xml?count=6')) {
      $xml = simplexml_load_file('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/quitecheesedoff.xml?count=6');
      $tweets = $xml->xpath("/statuses/status");

      foreach($tweets as $tweet) {
         $text = $tweet->text;
         $date = $tweet->created_at;
         echo '<div class="tweet"><b>' . $text . '</b>' . $date . '</div>';
      }
   }
   else echo 'error';
?>
```

Error

> Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/quitecheesedoff.xml?count=6)
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in

Comment: 1) This is definitely not a solution, but the `statuses/user_timeline/<screen_name>.xml` syntax is not recommended. Use the `?screen_name=` query parameter instead. 2) What's the error you're getting? 3) You should consider using JSON instead. In the past Twitter has showed that it wants to drop XML support and you should expect them to do that somewhere in the next 2 years.

Comment: What errors are being shown in the log when this runs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably making too many requests, triggering the hourly request limit of 150 - which becomes 75 with your code.

I'd recommend using

```
if (($xml = simplexml_load_file('...')) !== FALSE) {
```

instead. Your `$xml = ...` line is then not required anymore.

**Update**:

The 400 error isn't always actually used for bad requests at Twitter. Since it works 20% of the time I'd say it's safe to say there's something else.

- Avoid XML unless your programming language doesn't accept JSON (PHP does so use JSON!)
- Avoid using non-recommended URLs. Use `https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?count=6&screen_name=quitecheesedoff` instead.

In the past the 400 error was also given when Twitter's internal proxies made mistakes.

Comment: To clarify: the reason this is recommended is because the original code makes the request twice for no reason or benefit...

Comment: @horatio I must have read that question 5 times and thought something looked strange ... how did i not see that !!!!

Comment: :) "Tom" saw it too, he just didn't state it in an obvious manner. As a side question for Tom: 400 is supposed to be for malformed requests. Is this technically an illegal return code for a denial?

Comment: @horatio 400 is not an error you get for making too many requests. I have seen the 400 used in many contexts though, usually wrongly. I've updated my answer with some additional things that could be fixed.